# How to implement density-based clustering?

Tags: r, clustering, sparse, mathematica, dbscan

I’m looking to implement density-based clustering with R or Mathematica on a giant file (600,000 points on a 3 billion x 3 billion plane).
Is DBSCAN the right method for data that is this sparse? I am also anticipating a huge amount of noise. Which parameters would I tweak to account for this?

Comment: Why the close votes? OK, so the user wants to ultimately use R or Mathematica, this is not a code request question.There are some clear statistical aspects in the OP's question (ie. the use of DBSCAN with a large sparse noisy dataset). Maybe one can suggest the question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11418/density-based-spatial-clustering-of-applications-with-noise-dbscan-clustering) as being a possible duplicate (I think it is not) but that's a totally different criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a large dataset data as well as noisy data I strongly recommend that a dimensional reduction step is done prior to clustering. This should allow potentially irrelevant variation to be filtered out and the clustering algorithm to work in a lower dimensional space. Standard dimensional reduction techniques like [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) and [Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) (LSH) are two standard approaches.

Detecting density-based clusters in high-dimensional spaces, even when having noiseless data can be very demanding. High-dimensional density estimation is a typical scenario where the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) manifests. DBSCAN ultimately relies on finding fixed-radius nearest neighbours for each point. As the dimensionality of the data increases this nearest neighbour (NN) finding task becomes more and more attenuated. In addition (and most importantly) a standard distance metric as Euclidean distance gets potentially increasingly irrelevant. Therefore even if we have a distance and neighbourhood to work with that information is not very useful. This association between curse of dimensionality and NN-related tasks has been touched upon many time in CV, eg. see [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219373), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159070), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110043), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264109).

By the way, something "simple" like the following script where $N$ is quite larger than just 600$k$ as in your case, runs on my laptop (Intel i5 U-series) in under 5 minutes using ~10 GB of RAM. This is because the fixed-radius nearest neighbour problem mentioned above is solved within the library [dbscan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/index.html) using [$k$-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree); most NN-finding routines use some approximation approach; otherwise even cases with just a few more than tenths of thousands of points would get prohibitively large to work with when involving $O(n^2)$ requirements. So while not "instant" a use-case with 600$k$ points is definitely doable in R given a standard workstation and some appropriate dimensional reduction.

```
N = 10^7; p = 50;
Q = matrix(nrow = N, rt(N*p, df = 2))
library(dbscan)
W = dbscan(Q, eps= 0.01, minPts = 100) # About 4.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN will work, but you need a good index structure. Without a good index, it will be $O(n^2)$ which is too expensive.

If you have a lot of noise, increase minPts.

Comment: Can you kind of expand a bit? I always enjoy reading you insightful answers/comments on clustering issue but this post needs some extra context. How does `minPts` associate with what the user might experience noise-wise? How an index would help the time complexity? How much? Why would it be $O(n^2)$ to begin with?

Comment: See the Wikipedia article for DBSCAN complexity. If you have a lot of noise, a larger sample provides a more reliable density estimate.

Comment: That section of the Wikipedia article, while relating to your answer on the use of index structures, has nothing to do with the *noise* against `minPts` relation. You might want(ed) to comment that with larger `minPts` parameters is more probable that outliers/noisy data are not incorporated erroneously in a cluster/neighbourhood but that is not explained in your post or your comment...